# Update column value from array element inside before insert trigger

Tags: postgresql-11

i am trying to do a before insert trigger that updates one of the columns that will be inserted with a value taken from another column on the same record, however the catch is that that value is the first value of the said column after converting it to an array. when i include the function or the array i get a syntax error but the examples i have found for the proper syntax do not have the detail needed to make my code work.  Here is my code:

**Schema is as follows**

```
create table events (
  id int primary key,
  performers varchar,
  performer_id varchar
);
```

**Function is:**

```
create function events_set_performer() returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    performer_ varchar := '0';
BEGIN
    set NEW.performer_id = (string_to_array(NEW.performers,':'))[1];
    return new;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the exact error message.

Comment: This sounds like a horrible database design - it would be better to fix the data model and your application rather than using this ugly hack.